# Подсчет суммы по позициям

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день. Есть такой скрипт, который подсчитывает сумму по позициям путем перемножения:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Расчет стоимости номера
    $("#CountPriceInRoom").change(function() {
        var totalSum = 0;
        $("input[id^='pos'], select[id^='pos']").each(function() {
            var idElement = "#"+$(this).attr("id"), //Получаем id элемента
                priceField = parseInt($(idElement+"_price").text()), //Стоимость позиции
                countField = parseInt($(this).val()); //значение элемента

            $(idElement+"_count").text(priceField * countField); //Выводим сумму по позиции
            totalSum += priceField * countField;
        });
        $("#total-amount span").text(totalSum);
        $('#AllPrice2').val(totalSum);
    });
});
```

Если позиция priceField пуста, скрипт, соответственно, при перемножении показывает NaN, а мне нужно, чтобы показывал 0. Как его доработать?

Answer (score 1):

Как то так наверно:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Расчет стоимости номера
$("#CountPriceInRoom").change(function() {
    var totalSum = 0;
    $("input[id^='pos'], select[id^='pos']").each(function() {
        var idElement = "#"+$(this).attr("id"), //Получаем id элемента
            priceField = parseInt($(idElement+"_price").text()), //Стоимость позиции
            countField = parseInt($(this).val()); //значение элемента

        var outdata = priceField * countField;
        if (isNaN(outdata)) outdata = 0; //проверка на невозможность умножения

        $(idElement+"_count").text(outdata); //Выводим сумму по позиции
        totalSum += outdata;
    });
    $("#total-amount span").text(totalSum);
    $('#AllPrice2').val(totalSum);
    });
});
```

Comment: Все равно NaN.

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Ок. Спасибо. Для totalSum тоже нужно было прописать 

    if (isNaN(totalSum)) totalSum = 0;

Comment: ой, у вас, наверное, правильнее

Comment: Не за что, удачной разработки!

Comment: Ого а почему автор ответа стал "Cообщество ХэшКод" а не я?)

Comment: Вот такие глюки)